# How can I get the filtered model?

Tags: java, persistence, jtable, filtering, save

I'm working with JTables to display information that users can filter, and if the user saves after filtering I want to save the filtered table to a textfile for persistence (meaning anything that got filtered out will not be saved to the textfile).

For filtering I just followed the filtering part of this tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting and it works fine, but I'm not sure of any way that I can get a model of the current display as opposed to the underlying model that contains everything that hasn't been filtered out.

Is there any way to do this with this with the way that I'm filtering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Ask the table its number of rows (using `getRowCount()`), which will return the number of filtered (visible) rows. Iterate from 0 to the rowCount, convert each row index to the model index using `convertRowIndexToModel()`, and ask your model the data at each model index to build the list of filtered (visible) data.

Answer (score 2):

This code shows how to do this. Please note that B row is not printed to the input after the button is pressed.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class JTableFilterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[][] data = { { "A", 5 }, { "B", 2 }, { "C", 4 }, { "D", 8 } };
        String columnNames[] = { "Item", "Value" };
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        RowFilter<Object, Object> filter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>() {
            public boolean include(Entry entry) {
                Integer population = (Integer) entry.getValue(1);
                return population.intValue() > 3;
            }
        };

        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(
                model);
        sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Filtering Table");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Print values");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(int row = 0;row < table.getRowCount();row++) {
                    System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 0));
                }
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```